# How to serve json instead of html in angular?

Tags: json, angular

Is it possible at all?

I need to process some backend data, but instead of serving html page with results, I need to output it as json, for one url. How to prepare component to do that?

So the app serves standard html pages now. All of the components process some backend data first, and then use it to display results in html.

But I have one case where I need to output json, for further processing in another, external application. So json component will get data from the backend, just as others, and process it somehow. But how to output that processed data as json, with `Content-Type: application/json` http header?

Comment: you wan't to generate a json file with angular?
for a user or an api?

Comment: are you getting data from backend in <html> format or you want to prepare JSON file with angular

Comment: @fab For api, just one component, all others are standard angular components

Comment: angular is for the frontend, I suggest you to make that in the backend; you have to execute javaScript to use angular, you can't simple call a url and get the json that is made with angular

Comment: So you want to get some data from the server, turn it into JSON, and then output it somewhere? Since when you're using Angular you're in a browser, you can't just save it to disk. You'd have to send it back to the server in another request. It would be better to just do the whole task on the server. Why do you want to use Angular for data processing? it's a GUI framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Angular starts after browser loads all the libraries. If something else than browser access the angular app, all it will get is app/index.html page from src directory. So there is no way it can create json with `application/json` http header. Because first browser gets the headers, then angular starts.

I go to the backend indeed.